# Canvas Class Constructor Function

Tags: python, class, oop, canvas

I am working on an assignment involving classes. I have completed the two other class that have been asked of us: Point, and Rectangle. I am currently working on the canvas class and I am not sure what to put in its constructor. The purpose of the canvas is to store rectangles that you have added to the canvas and compare them through multiple functions.

My question is, how do i create a constructor for this class if there is nothing originally in it

Comment: @martineau Could you please reword that, I still have my my python training wheels on aha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the constructor initialize the class instance's internal container of objects (Points and Rectangles in this case) to an empty state. Presumably the class will have one or more methods defined to add such objects to it later, after it's created.

That's basically how the [`Tkinter.Canvas`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) works. Its constructor accepts a large number of keyword option arguments that define other attributes of the widget, such as its background color, height and width, etc (as detailed in [this](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) reference).